# Формат TIME() в MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Хочу настроить формат **TIME()**, но, если я оставляю скобки пустыми, то получаю ошибку, как на скрине.
Мне нужно, чтобы отображались дата и время (**yyyy-mm-dd + hh:mi**). Что мне нужно записать в скобки, чтобы отображался такой формат и не было ошибки?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У типа time нет пустых круглых скобок и хранит он только время, без даты. Дату с временем хранят в типе datetime. Но понятия "формат" при хранении даты нет. Он в БД садится во внутреннем, двоичном формате. А формат ввода и вывода значений дат/времени в человекочитаемом виде задается в параметрах сессии или явно в момент получения значений из БД

Comment: datetime я, кстати, упустил) вот, если ввожу без скобок - то проходит, ошибки нет

Comment: Не путайте хранение значения и его отображение. То, что Вам надо - это отображение, и его следует формировать в запросе (например, функцией DATE_FORMAT). А хранение - это внутренне дело сервера, и им управлять нельзя.